# tunneling socket could not be established statuscode=407, I'm getting this error on searching packages in atom

Tags: sockets, atom-editor

When I'm trying to install new packages in my atom text editor, I'm getting this error. How to fix this Issue.

You can see the snapshot here
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've read many articles, and so far no concert solution for this problem, basically if you are behind a corporate proxy the Atom interface for package search/installation won't work. You still can install packages but only over apm command line:

This is what worked for me, kind of a compilation form many other "solutions":

1 - running `apm install --check` will probability return failed:

```
example:
C:\Users\{{user}}>apm install --check
Checking for native build tools failed
```

2 - To fix that, open git-bash.exe  (under C:\Program Files\Git)

3 - edit and run the following command line on gitbash:

```
HOME=/c/Users/{{ user }}/.atom/.node-gyp/ /c/Users/{{ user }}/AppData/Local/atom/{{ atom_app_version }}/resources/app/apm/bin/node /c/Users/{{ user }}/AppData/Local/atom/{{ atom_app_version }}/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js "install" "--target=2.0.5" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--arch=x64" "--ensure" "--verbose" "--proxy=http://{{ user }}:{{ password }}@myproxy.com:{{ port}}"
```

> tip:  following the paths make it easy on filling the blanks

5- This should fix the apm install, run `apm install --check` to check:

```
C:\Users\{{user}}>apm install --check
Checking for native build tools done
```

After all this, you should be able to install any Atom package you need over apm command line:

```
apm install go-plus
```